# Open Viewcontroller(no Stroyboard) from swift class method- React native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-bridge

I'm trying to load `Initialviewcontroller`, from swift class

My swift class (**ChatManager.swift**)

```
 import Foundation;

import UIKit;


@objc(ChatManager)
class ChatManager: NSObject {

  @objc func addEvent(name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber) -> Void {
    // Date is ready to use!

  }

  @objc func startChat ()
  {
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initialViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

My **Appdelegate.m**

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"RnBridgeBoldChat"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

My `InitialViewController` is an `objective-c` class which loads UI programmatically.

My intention is to load `Initialviewcontroller` from a method in swift class, I will call that particular method from react native via NativeModules.

```
  @objc func startChat ()
  {
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initialViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Above function showing error as

> "ChatManager has no member NavigationController".

Please let me know how to call this viewcontroller from that swift class.

Comment: the viewController exists in the storyboard ?

Comment: there is no storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func startChat (){
    let initialVC = initialViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initialVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22701745).

Comment: Its not working as  there is no navigation controller

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same question! @Kartiikeya